# com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Unexpected close tag

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I need you help in understanding following exceptions we are getting sporadically.

We are consuming soap webservices, and we are getting following error while parsing the response. Our parser is a JAR client, generated using the wsdl file, which parse the response using JAX-WS.

Following exceptions are coming:
**javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Unexpected close tag ; expected .
**
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [737,76]
        at

com.sun.xml.ws.handler.SOAPMessageContextImpl.getMessage(SOAPMessageContextImpl.java:81)
        at mobile.rbc.mobiliser.common.logger.LoggingHandler.handleMessage(LoggingHandler.java:97)
        at mobile.rbc.mobiliser.common.logger.LoggingHandler.handleMessage(LoggingHandler.java:37)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.handler.HandlerProcessor.callHandleMessageReverse(HandlerProcessor.java:336)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.handler.HandlerProcessor.callHandlersResponse(HandlerProcessor.java:209)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.handler.ClientSOAPHandlerTube.callHandlersOnResponse(ClientSOAPHandlerTube.java:159)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.handler.HandlerTube.processResponse(HandlerTube.java:160)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:608)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:557)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:542)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:439)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:222)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:135)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:109)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:89)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:118)

**Note: Same set of code is working fine during the course of time.**

Comment: Hi, Is this issue resolved ? I am also facing same problem. Please provide solution if available. I am getting error in Apache CXF environment but when run standalone it is working properly.

Comment: No, its not. Still looking for some solution

Comment: Hi JainAnk, provide complete url of wsdl, I mean intead of http://x.x.x.x/ur_endpoint use like - http://x.x.x.x/ur_endpoint?wsdl